# Continue php after page closed exec() ffmpeg

Tags: php, html, post, ffmpeg

I am wondering how I can continue a php page after `exec()` ([ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)) and the page has been closed.

I have a form that allows people to convert their video files with ffmpeg but if the user clicks away the page the exec() keeps going but anything after this exec is not being executed.

```
<?php
   if (!empty($_POST) && $imgDir) {
      exec('"/dir/to/ffmpeg" -f image2 -i "' . $imgDir . '" -r 12 -s 610x489 /dir/to/out.avi', $out);

      /* INSERT statement (Not being executed) */
      $sql = "INSERT INTO requests (userID,image) VALUES (?,?)";
      $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute([$user_id, $imgDir]);
   }
?>
```

I want a user to be able to click an away the page, so they don't have to wait and can download their file later.

Comment: you probably want to offload the conversion process to a background script (e.g. a job triggered regularly by cron). The web page would just put a request into a queue (e.g. in a db table) and save the file. The background service would then pick the next item off the queue, process it, and mark it complete. Then you have to consider how to notify the user. You could email them, or have a status page where they can check their jobs and download any files that are ready, or both, or some other process of your choosing. Perhaps you can allow the user to specify how they want to be informed.

Comment: P.S. are you certain the INSERT query isn't being executed? It could just be that the SQL query is failing...have you got PDO set up to throw exceptions when that happens? Are you logging exceptions? I note also that the SQL block is not inside the `if (!empty($_POST)...` block and will therefore execute even when the user has not submitted any data...I doubt that's desirable.

Comment: @ADyson you are right, I think running this in the background is better. The queue is perfect for when multiple people want to convert at the same time. (I copied my code the wrong way, the query is within the if statement in the actual code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common solution in this type of scenario is to offload the conversion process to a background script (e.g. a job triggered regularly by cron). This avoids problems with long-running processes timing out, or issues with external command-line processes not returning correctly.

The web page would just put a request into a queue (e.g. in a db table) and save the file.

The background service would then pick the next item off the queue, process it, and mark it complete.

Then you have to consider how to notify the user. You could email them, or have a status page where they can check their jobs and download any files that are ready, or both, or some other process of your choosing. Perhaps you can allow the user to specify how they want to be informed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start this command from PHP in the background, you can run non-blocking processes by this pattern:

```
if(is_resource($proc = proc_open($cmd, [['pipe', 'r'], ['pipe', 'w'], ['pipe', 'w']], $pipes)))
{
    stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], false);
    stream_set_blocking($pipes[2], false);
```

On a Linux system you can start a command with a prepended `nohup`, e.g.

```
$cmd = 'nohup "/dir/to/ffmpeg" -f image2 -i "' . $imgDir . '" -r 12 -s 610x489 /dir/to/out.avi'
```

After using `nohup` you can even exit the process which started the new process. It will be detached from parent process.

Comment: Does this run the ffmpeg in the background or the whole php file/process?

Comment: @Tygo `proc_open` starts a new system process similar to `exec` and the other system functions but using pipes instead of returning function values / arguments by ref. `stream_set_blocking` does not wait for EOF when reading from stream. However, when the parent process finishes without waiting for childprocesses are finished, childs are still killed unless you use the `nohup` linux command to detach the child. In short: The child process, i.e. `ffmpeg` runs in background.

Comment: @Tygo you do not even need to use pipes and set non-blocking mode at all if you don't want to receive output data from child's STDOUT/STDERR (run and forget).